# Javascript displaying a div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am hoping you guys can help me with this.  I have the following code

```
  </textarea>
    <br />Word Count: <input type="text" name="c" value="311" size="5" onkeyup="cnt(document.script.w,this)" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myNumValue = document.getElementById('c').value;
    var myNum = parseInt(myNumValue);
    var upperLimit=200;
    var lowerLimit=10;

    if(upperLimit == lowerLimit)
       {
 document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility='visible';
       }
    </script>

    <div id="div1" style="visibility: hidden;">
    Super cool hidden div!
    </div>
```

For some reason, I cannot get the div to show.  I have tried setting the upper and lower the same and using == in if, anything inside of the if displays (for example if a do a document.write it will show up) but for some reason the div will not show.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Kevin

Comment: Is it possible that the 'div1' object hasn't been created at the time this javascript is being run? You may want to put the 'div1' declaration before the the javascript.

Comment: To add to the above. Do an alert on document.getElementById('div1') to ensure it is returning an object.

Comment: To add further to the above: It's generally considered good practice to put your scripts just before your `</body>` tag, to avoid this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that the input has no `id` so, as Sarfraz says, `document.getElementById('c')` will error.

That is not the only critical problem though.

Your script is not in a function, so it will run as soon as it is parsed.

The div element appears in the document **after** the script element, so the browser doesn't know it exists at the time the script runs.

`document.getElementById('div1')` will therefore error.

Either move the script element to after the div element, or wrap it in a function and delay execution until an event that will fire after the element exists (such as onload (standard) or ondomready (provided by many JS libraries).

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified `id` attribute for your field:

```
<input type="text" name="c" value="311" size="5" onkeyup="cnt(document.script.w,this)" />
```

Should be:

```
<input type="text" name="c" id="c" value="311" size="5" onkeyup="cnt(document.script.w,this)" />
```

Because you are missing the `id` there, you are most likely getting an error and your script halts in the middle;  a reason why your code does not reach that `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to close your `<script>` tag or did you just not cut/paste it?

The line

```
if(upperLimit == lowerLimit)
```

is never true; you just defined upperLimit to be not equal to lowerLimit.

Comment: Quoting from OP: **I have tried setting the upper and lower the same and using ==**

Comment: I'll be darned, it was there. Huh.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: OP is using ` style="visibility: hidden;"`

Answer (score -1):

u have not created object of div1
first create object.

```
<div id="div1" style="visibility: hidden;"> 
  Super cool hidden div!
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myNumValue = document.getElementById('c').value;
var myNum = parseInt(myNumValue);
var upperLimit=200;
var lowerLimit=200;

if(upperLimit == lowerLimit)
{
    document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility='visible';
}
</script>
```